# Where did the "apps" tab disappear?

Tags: support, status-completed

I may just be missing something, but there used to be an "apps" tab on the main page, which showed you a (sorted by vote) list of all the apps and libraries.

I can't find it anymore. Where did it disappear to?

Comment: Probably belongs on meta.

Comment: @Randolpho this isn't stack overflow, there is no meta.stackapps.com

Answer (score 4):

I wish I could blame a failed blow out preventer - fixed :)